# Incrementing numbers in REXX

Tags: rexx

I have a requirement where I take a SUBSTR (e.g st_detail = "%BOM0007992739871P", st_digit = SUBSTR(st_detail, 8, 10) ). I have to do some validations on the st_digit and if it is valid change "%BOM0002562186P" to "%BOM0002562186C". My code works fine upto this. But I was asked to increment st_digit (I used st_digit = st_digit + 1 ) and print 100 valid st_digits and append it with C. so I put the code in a loop and display st_detail. But when i ran it i got "%BOM0007.99273987E+9C" after first increment. Please help on how to display "%BOM0007992739872C"? (NOTE: this is a reference only and I can't display the validation logic here and my code works fine. The extra code i added was the code I used here)

```
out_ctr = 1
DO while out_ctr < 101
   /* validations */
   IF valid THEN
     say st_digit " is valid"
   ELSE
     say st_digit " is invalid"
   st_digit = st_digit + 1
   out_ctr = out_ctr + 1
END
```

Comment: Please submit your trace  (relevant part only). As shown your code is valid although I would code it as Do out_ctr = 1 To 100. You also appear to be incrementing st_digit whether it is valid or invalid. You should also, whilst trying to figure out what is wrong, show the value of st_digit before and after increment. But I suspect the error is elsewhere.

Comment: You could also split st_detail into three parts - the first 8 bytes, st_digits and the trailing character. Then increment the digits and finally concatenate all parts back into one : st_detail = part1||part2||part3

Comment: *-* st_digit = st_digits + 1
           >V>   "7992739871"
           >L>   "1"
           >O>   "7.99273987E+9"

Comment: I suspect the problem arises after assignment. You advised to split, I already did it, and it still shows the same.

Comment: @VinayPaladi You're right to suspect that, and if you run your code with `Trace I` as NicC suggests, you'd know it for sure.  That's the very first thing any Rexx programmer will do to debug a misbehavior.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the NUMERIC setting was " 9 0 SCIENTIFIC ". I changed it to          NUMERIC DIGITS 12, So, now it works.

```
parse numeric my_numeric_settings
say my_numeric_settings   /* 9 0 SCIENTIFIC */
NUMERIC DIGITS 16
parse numeric my_numeric_settings
say my_numeric_settings  /* 16 0 SCIENTIFIC */
```

It's because I used **SUBSTR(st_detail, 8, 10)**,So, st_digit is of length 10, which is greater than the DEFAULT setting of **"9 0 SCIENTIFIC"**, So by changing it to either **"NUMERIC DIGITS 10"** or **"NUMERIC DIGITS 12"** the code worked.